# How to use multiple chunks to run same process parallel?

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing

I have created a chunks of 4 and want to pass each chunks to do the same process parallel on each chunk.
Let's say I have list of files in wb_path and total count if 200. I want to do some process on each file. So I have created 4 chunks each of 50 files below.

I want to do process parallell on all 4 chuns together.

```
entries = os.listdir(wb_path)
df=pd.DataFrame(entries,columns=['Wk_nm'])
print(df)

#specify number of rows in each chunk
n=50

#split DataFrame into chunks
list_df = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(df),n)]
```

How to write the loop after creating chunks which is list_df to process parallel for each chunks?

```
entries = os.listdir(wb_path)
df=pd.DataFrame(entries,columns=['Wk_nm'])
print(df)

#specify number of rows in each chunk
n=50

#split DataFrame into chunks
list_df = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(df),n)]
```

Comment: Please don't use unrelated tags.